# Digit Recognition using KNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, image-recognition

I'm a newbie to this machine learning concepts!
I've made a model and trained it to an accuracy of 98% using KNN-Classifier, but I'm unable to test the model using an image as the input.
Each datapoint contains an equivalent of 8X8 image of a digit. When I convert this into a numpy array , It gives a me list of integers between 0.0 to 16.0 (dtype = float64).
But the problem , I'm unable to break down the input image into the dateset's corresponding image. 
The following is the [executed in CMD prompt , Python version - 3x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IbCQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print an array as an image, use:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array = np.array([0,0,0,10,9,0,0,0,0,0,5,15,0,0,9,5,0,0,14,10,0,7,16,4,0,5,16,7,5,16,6,0,0,11,16,16,16,14,0,0,0,3,4,11,16,8,0,0,0,0,0,7,16,2,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,0,0,0])
plt.imshow(array.reshape(8,8))
plt.show()
```

Next time, make sure your data can be easily copy and pasted, pictures are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you have provided it is impossible to know what is wrong. Also, 0.0 and 16.0 are not integers, they are floats. Before training ML algorithm it is a good idea to normalize the images to a maximum of 1.0 like so `numpy_Image = numpy_Image/np.max(numpy_Image)` . For KNN (and almost everything else) training and test images have to have the same size. "But the problem , I'm unable to break down the input image into the dateset's corresponding image." - post the code and the error message you get in terminal, please.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Sir. Your suggestion was highly useful . Now , my model is working fine. Sorry, Since I was totally new to this platform, so didn't know how to post stuff . Thanks again :)